# Is $(\mathbb{Z}_4, +_4)$ isomorphic to $(\langle i\rangle, *)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Now, I am not sure, but I think that the second group is cyclic, because of the way it's defined $(\langle i\rangle,*)$. $i$ is probably the generator of the group. But, how can I prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_4, +_4)$ is isomorphic to that group?

Comment: What is $(\langle i\rangle, \ast)$?

Comment: That is what i don't know, it is given to me like that, i thought it just represents a cyclic group, since symbol for the generator of the group are those parentheses <>. But i am not sure about that, i just assume that it could be it.

Comment: Maybe it is $i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\ast$ is just complex multiplication.

Comment: Assuming that $i = \sqrt(-1)$ and $\ast$ is the normal multiplication of $\mathbb{C}$, $(<i>,\ast)$ is a cyclic group of order $4$, thus isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably they mean $\;\langle i,\,\cdot\rangle\;$ is the multiplicative group in $\;\Bbb C\;$ generated by $\;i\;$ , which indeed is cyclic and of order four, and thus both given groups are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $i$ is the imaginary number such that $i^2=-1$.

You see that $i^1=i$, $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$, $i^4=1$ and the pattern repeats.

This is the same pattern in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, 1=1, 1+1=2, 1+1+1=3, 1+1+1+1=0.

Hence you can construct an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ to $\langle i\rangle$ by mapping 1 to $i$.